# jQuery.ajax and not parsed via GET request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to parse value (adults) from select option field through a GET request with the use of AJAX. I can parse the value through the url - by checking the url with the alert of the url in the jQuery function. But I can't retrieve the value within the page I do the GET request.

jQuery.ajax

```
<script>
  $('.roomAvailable').change(
   function roomChanges(data) {
     var over = '<div id="overlaysRooms">' 
              + '<div id="loading"><div class="loaders"></div><div id="loadertextsearch">Vent Venligst...</div>' 
              + '</div>';
     $(over).appendTo('.rooms');
     $('.rooms').addClass('overlaysRooms');
     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       data: {
         'arrival': '<?php echo strval($_GET[' arrival ']); ?>',
         'departure': '<?php echo strval($_GET['departure ']);?>',
         'adults': $("#adults option:selected").val(),
         'hotelId': '<?php echo strval($_GET[' hotelId ']);?>',
         'room1': $("#rooms option:selected").val()
       },
       url: '<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelRoomAvailable.php',

       success: function(data) {
         alert(this.url);
         $('#roomsavailable').replaceWith(data);
         $('#overlaysRooms').remove();
       },
       error: function(xhr) {}
     })

   });

</script>
```

hotelRoomAvailable.php:

```
<?php
  var_dump(intval($_GET['adults']));
?>
```

Alert value: http://example.com/hotels/hotelRoomAvailable.php?arrival=03%2F13%2F2015&departure=03%2F18%2F2015&adults=5&hotelId=375477&room1=1

So when I check with var_dump to retrieve value of adults I get nothing. Why is it the value is not parsed to the page when I see the value is parsed in the alert message from jQuery ?

Comment: Try opening your browser developer tools or user a third party tool like fiddler to see what request is actually being sent to your server in order to verify your code is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: What is the value of `alert(this.url);`?

Comment: @Quentin the clear value is e.g http://example.com/hotels/hotelRoomAvailable.php?arrival=03%2F13%2F2015&departure=03%2F18%2F2015&adults=5&hotelId=375477&room1=1

Comment: What if you insert, just before `$('#roomsavailable').replaceWith(data);`, the line `alert($('#roomsavailable').length)`?

Comment: Then I get 0 @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (almost certainly) getting the expected result back from the PHP script you are calling.

> What if you insert, just before
>   `$('#roomsavailable').replaceWith(data);`, the line
>   `alert($('#roomsavailable').length)`? –  Quentin
>
> Then I get `0` @Quentin –  Troels Johannesen

The problem is, that `$('#roomsavailable')` doesn't find any element with that id, so there is nothing to replace with the data you get.

You need to make sure that an element with that id exists in the document.

Comment: There is - <ul id="roomsavailable" class="booking-list"></ul>

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen — That you get a `0` with `alert($('#roomsavailable').length)` proves that there is not. There might have been when you loaded the document, but there isn't when you ran the code. Possibly you have already called `replaceWith` on it which would have removed it.

Comment: Exactly the issue! - was called already and therefor it was non-exiting afterwards. Many thanks Quentin, and thanks for very good explanation! @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

Please just add the _GET variables to the url.

And remove the "type" and "data" variables completely.

Comment: Adding them manually is a horrible approach. The existing approach (with `data` ) is far better as it will escape them automatically. Removing `type` won't make a difference.

Comment: Btw, I tend to use encodeUri() on my url string, which takes care of the escaping and encoding issues.  I wouldn't call it horrible, because there are more than 1 way to skin a cat...but I would say that I learned something today and will try out this approach your mentioned @Quentin.  Tks too.